# AngularJS filter

Tags: angularjs, javascript-framework

I have the following code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText">
<div ng-repeat="user in student.suggested_users | filter:searchText" ng-init="current_user = getUser(user)">{{current_user.name}}
</div>
```

This will help me in filtering objects from student.suggested_users array. But i want to filter on the name of the current_user object that is initialized for every user object.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example from my project: https://github.com/lucassus/mongo_browser/blob/master/app/assets/templates/databases.html and explanation how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/JtAZM/1/

Basically instead `ng-model="filterValue"` you should use `ng-model="filterValue.{akey}"`

Comment: Thanks luacassus! Do we have an option where we say just filter by name and user_id of the user and not anything else like **<input type="text" ng-model="searchText.$(name || user_id)">**